# How to change the date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using one jquery date picker,
with using picker i am getting date in like this format
Friday, May 21, 2010

Now i want to add one day in this date so i think, i can only do if i change the date in exact format like
21/5/2010

I want to only convert that bcz i want to add one day to the particular date.
So what do u suggest me? How can I do that? 
Can i do without converting it ?

thanks in advance....

Comment: take a look at this http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

[datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the formatting options given by others, you should add using date objects rather than to the string representation of the date object.

I.E.

```
// add 5 days to today
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to detail what jQuery plugin do you use.
Is it this one? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

If so, then when you cann `getDate` method, you'll get `Date` object representing a date. You can easily manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The date format has nothing to do with how dates are stored; it only affects the way dates are *displayed*. JavaScript has a native Date object and jQuery UI's Datepicker allows to access such object:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate

Once you have a Date object, you can alter it to suit your needs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Finally, you can feed it back into Datepicker:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate